# Read SNS notification in AWS Lambda function written in C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am reading SNS notification in AWS Lambda function written in C# as below.

```
public string FunctionHandler(SNSEvent snsEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        string retVal = "No Message";
        foreach (var record in snsEvent.Records)
        {
            var snsRecord = record.Sns;
            Console.WriteLine($"[{record.EventSource} {snsRecord.Timestamp}] Message = {snsRecord.Message}");
            retVal = $"[{record.EventSource} {snsRecord.Timestamp}] Message = {snsRecord.Message}";
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

I have published the Lambda function to AWS and also subscribed the SNS topic to this Lambda function.

How should I test this Lambda fucntion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write small console app, which sends messages to SNS topic. You can use Aws SNS nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService/).

Should be something like this:

```
var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(credentials, endpointRegion)

await _client.PublishAsync(new PublishRequest(_topicArn, message));
```

Don't forget to include your [credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can publish test messages to an SNS topic via the AWS console.

[image: Button in SNS, publish to topic]

After clicking the button you'll have various options specifying MessageAttributes and the Message payload. You'll also get a handy `Json message generator` which I recommend since it's sometimes hard sticking with the SNS specific format.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Postman to publish a message to the TopicArn and then check Cloudwatch logs for any of your Console.Writeline logs that you are writing out.

For more information on the format of a message and how to publish one to a TopicArn, check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html

and this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html